# how to fetch payload from quick replies in botpress

Tags: bots

i am  new to botpress and trying to make simple order bot with botpress. but not using messenger,etc just trying to make simple question answer bot. in available example on github uses content.yml but it gives error

> [Renderer] Renderer not defined (#welcome)
>          at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/botpress-pro-nightly-2018-12-24-darwin-x64/pizza/node_modules/botpress/src/renderers/index.js:163:13

**index.js**

```
module.exports = bp => {

  Object.keys(renderers).forEach(name => {
    bp.renderers.register(name, renderers[name])
  })

    bp.hear(/GET_STARTED|hello|hi|test|hey|holla/i, (event, next) => {

        console.log(event);
        event.reply('#welcome')
        var yes=event.welcome.quick_replies[0].payload;
        bp.logger.info('answer:', yes);

    })
    }
```

so i use this type of code in **renderers.js** it works but not able to fetch reply

```
 module.exports = {
        text: data => {
            return {text: data.text, typing: !!data.typing}
        },
        '#welcome': data => ({
            typing: true,
            text: 'Hey there! Would you like to order?',
            quick_replies: [
                    {
                        content_type: 'text',
                        title: 'Yes',
                        payload: 'Y'
                    },
                    {
                        content_type: 'text',
                        title: 'No',
                        payload: 'N'
                    }
                ],

    })   ,
    '#askLocation': data => ({
        typing: true,
        text: 'Please click this button for me to know where you are!',
        quick_replies: [
                {
                    content_type: 'location',
                    title: 'location',
                    payload: 'location'
                }
            ],

    })
}
```